# Add context menu items to specific file extensions

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu, file-extension

I think the title says all I want: I want to add context menu items for a specific file type like the yellow marked ones in the screenshot. **Which registry changes do I have to make?** In my case I want to assign *ir.exe* to *.rb* files.

[image]

Comment: There is a great answer on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype

Comment: Thank you :) If you can post this as an answer, I can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a great [answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123762/add-menu-item-to-windows-context-menu-only-for-specific-filetype):

> **1) Identify the file type (ProgID) for .jpg files**
>
> This can be done by checking the default value of
>   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jpg`. It could be anything based on what you've
>   installed, but for the purposes of this example, we'll call it
>   `jpegfile`, a common default.
>
> **2) Set the context menu item (verb) properties for that file type**
>
> You can set per-user context menu items in
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell`. This key has a
>   list of verbs for the file type. There is a similar key in
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell`, and these are
>   the system defaults for the file type. You can put a verb key there
>   too, but if the same key exists in HKCU, it will be overridden, so be
>   advised.
>
> **3) Set the command value**
>
> The bare minimum key value that needs to be set to get it to work is
>   the default value of the `command` subkey. You need to set that with
>   the path to your application, like so:
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell\open_with_myapp\command` would be set to `"c:\path\to\myapp.exe" "%1"`. Now a context menu for
>   .jpg files will have a "open_with_myapp" item which will launch your
>   app when clicked, and pass the file name of the selected file as a
>   parameter. Of course, how your application processes parameters is up
>   to you, so you'd need to set the parameter string to something your
>   app can process.
>
> **4) Set other verb properties**
>
> I'd imagine you're probably going to want the context menu item to
>   read something a little more friendly than the key name. You can have
>   the context menu display whatever label you want for your item by
>   setting the default value of that key (`open_with_myapp`).
>
> That's your basic overview. Definitely check out my answer to this
>   question about associating a file, which has a similar answer:
>
> - [Create registry entry to associate file extension with application in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c/2069565#2069565)

Answer (score 0):

There's a freeware (portable) which does this registry edit, and that function at least seems to work on Windows 10:

https://defaultprogramseditor.com/

[image]