# How to add context menu item for files in general, in Windows?

Tags: windows, context-menu

in order to add context menu for directories and explorer background, one can follow instructions [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/257178/how-to-create-a-shortcut-or-context-menu-item-for-nearly-any-windows-setting/).

To add context menu for specific file extensions, one can follow instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/737693/add-context-menu-items-to-specific-file-extensions)

but I can't seem to find a way to add context menu items for all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I looked on the internet and found a solution similar to your problem, you can refer to it. [Add Search Everything context menu item to all files](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5944)