Why doesn’t option in context menu for .JS files appear as expected?
In Windows 10 registry I've added a new key in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.js\shell\Run in Node.js\command and changed the variable to C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe "%1".
The structure looks like this:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
└── SystemFileAssociations
    └── .js
        └── shell
            └── Run in Node.js
                └── command

Despite restarting the system my new custom option still doesn't appear when I right-click on .js files.
What else can I try?

There are several questions on this site about adding context menus. Here's one: https://superuser.com/questions/737693/add-context-menu-items-to-specific-file-extensions
